# Please Identify this outdoor plant?

Tags: identification, outdoor

I saw this outdoor plant yesterday.

What’s the name of this plant?

Also, can it easily be propagated to a pot?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: to help future askers, where did you see this? What country?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a rubber fig (*Ficus elastica*). It's funny that you say it is an outdoor plant, because in my climate (Europe) it is an indoor plant (so I didn't expect this one), I have one in my living room. It contains, like all fig plants, white milky sap which can irritate the skin so be careful when pruning it.

It propagates very easy by cuttings. Mine was a tip cutting with 4 leaves and was put in water first, when roots appeared after a few weeks it was put in a container with soil.

Comment: +1. Фикус. They seem to be rather hard to kill through lack of sunlight or water.